# iOS - Use same constraints for different iPad sizes, just scaling the view?

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad, autolayout, nslayoutconstraint

I have an app for both 12-inch iPad Pro and iPad Air. They have same aspect ratio. 
But when using auto-layout, constraints of same value make app look different on 2 devices because they are tied to point size of screen.

Is it possible to have some kind of reference screen coordinate system for constraints or maybe other approach to achieve visuals just being scaled on different screen sizes of same aspect ratio?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can use `multiplier` property to set constraints relative to the screen size or whatever you choose. For example, if you set it to `0.3`, it means 30% of what you constrain to. For example, width of your custom view will be 30% of width of superview.

[image]

Also, you can use `UIStackView`. It takes care of resizing views inside appropriately. And Apple recommends using it all the time wherever possible.

**Example of left 10% margin.**

```
        let leftMarginGuide = UILayoutGuide()
        view.addLayoutGuide(leftMarginGuide)

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            leftMarginGuide.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor),
            leftMarginGuide.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor),
            leftMarginGuide.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor),
            leftMarginGuide.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.heightAnchor, multiplier: 0.1)
            ])
```

Comment: With multiplier I will need to do it for all of hundreds constraints in my Storyboard - tie them to height or width of screen - that doesn't look like efficient approach) I just want to scale whole thing to new screen size

Comment: Then use Stack Views

Comment: @GeorgeFedoseev, by the way, usual leading/trailing constraints can't help you in your case?

Comment: I am using normal constraints including leading and trailing, but they are tied to pixels. I want, for example, 10% screen width margin left on iPad air be 10% screen width on iPad Pro

Comment: Ok, look. You can create your custom left/right layout guide. For example, for left: leading anchor matches superview leading anchor, and width anchor equals to superview width anchor with multiplier 0.1. It will be 10% of screen width. Then you constrain your views to that layout guide, exactly to the right anchor. The same aproach for right one

Comment: Yeah I can do that, but it will be a lot more work than just scaling everything. I guess what I want is just fundamentally not "how things are done" in autolayout UI system

Comment: @GeorgeFedoseev, there is no such thing as relative "10dp" in Android. So, fundamentally you should think about layout differently.

Comment: I do recommend trying UIStackView, if you didn't try.

Comment: You are welcome. If you have a specific problem, feel free to ask. I will try to suggest a solution.